# Visual Studio: default settings

Tags: visual-studio, installation

We have many developers here using MSVC 2008 and I want to standardize the Visual Studio settings and project setup.

In particular, I want:

1) All of the settings in the Tools -> Options to be the same (especially the tab settings!)

2) We have a source repository where we have a shared folder. The shared folder has header files/code that we re-use in multiple solutions (.sln) developed by different people. I want all new VC project created to automatically include (/I) the directories and link to the shared .lib/dll in that shared folder. (Note: this process has become so un-necessarily labor-intensive where each time we create a new solution, we have to re-type these include/lib names over and over)

Could someone please save us and point us to the right solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For #1, you can easily set up one Visual Studio environment, and then use the Import/Export Settings (under the Tools menu) to save a settings file that can be loaded into everyone's environment.

For #2, you could [try creating a project template](http://www.carlosag.net/Articles/createVSTemplate.aspx), so that whenever someone created a new project, they could use that template and it would include those items automatically.

Answer (score 1):

For tab settings and whatnot, you can use the Tools -> Import and Export Settings to create a standard settings file that you could check into source control.  Any new developers could pull that and import it into their Visual Studio settings.

Answer (score 0):

For 1 a novel approach would be to use Microsoft's Live Mesh [Sync VS Settings with Live Mesh](http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/archive/2008/06/30/sync-your-visual-studio-settings-with-live-mesh.aspx). It would be an easy way to keep all your developers using the same VS settings, although I could see that causing problems once individuals start customising to their own tastes.